# Accessing data of another class whose object was sent as parameter in constructor

Tags: c++

I'm working on creating a simulator for RISC.

Below are a different part of codes relevant to my question.

main.cpp

```
memory* main_memory;
processor* cpu;
main_memory = new memory (verbose);    //memory classs implemented correctly
cpu = new processor (main_memory, verbose);

interpret_commands(main_memory, cpu);// takes to commands class
```

In processor.cpp, I have to access a function of memory class that is public.

memory.cpp:

```
uint32_t memory::read_word (uint32_t address) {
            // some calculation and returns a hex word at address
}
```

processor.cpp:

```
#include "memory.h"
void processor::execute(unsigned int num, bool breakpoint_check){

    if(some condition){

           //call read_word at address
    }
}
```

I do have a parameterized constructor in processor.cpp that has memory class pointer:

```
processor::processor(memory* main_memory, bool verbose){

}
```

The question is, how can I call read_word function(of class memory) from the execute function (of class processor)?
Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Here's the thing about bugs. If you don't know what they are, how do you know what is the relevant code? Heck, what is the relevant problem?

Comment: Side note: you probably don't need any dynamic allocations, and if you do, [avoid `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new). [Use a smart pointer.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: lol @JohnZwinck. Sorry have been working on simulator whole night :) Updated it now.

Comment: @user4581301, I updated the question. 

I need to access read_word() from execute ().

Comment: If the `processor` constructor stored the `main_memory` pointer it was given in `somePointer` and you have a computed `address`, `somePointer->read_word(address);` ought to do it.

Comment: Have you peeked at [RISC-V simulator for x86-64](https://github.com/rv8-io/rv8)?

Comment: @user4581301, so, should I store the address of main_memory in the processor constructor and then use this address in the execute() to call read_word from there?

Comment: I mean this as politely as possible: That question says you're not ready to write a CPU simulator in C++. Get yourself [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the language with simpler problems before attempting this. Trying to learn to program with a task like this is going to leave you frustrated and burned out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store the `main_memory*` in the constructor as a member variable, so you can use it later in another member function:

```
processor::processor(memory* main_memory, bool verbose)
    : _main_memory(main_memory)
{}

void processor::execute(unsigned int num, bool breakpoint_check){
    if(some condition){
        _main_memory->read_word(...);
    }
}
```

And add `memory* _main_memory = nullptr` inside `class processor`.

Comment: What's my_address here? Is it like address of current instruction as in pc? Cause the constructor is not getting any address argument.

Comment: What's the _main_memory(main_memory)?

Comment: `_main_memory(main_memory)` is an initialization list.  It's the usual way to initialize member variables, though if you prefer you can just say `_main_memory = main_memory;` inside the constructor body.

Comment: Oh, I got it. It was supposed to be memory* _main_memory= nullptr in the class processor.